# ClamAV reporting PDFs as encrypted that are not encrypted (or at least not password protected)

Tags: pdf, encryption, antivirus, clamav

I am having issues with ClamAV scanning PDF files and reporting back that they are encrypted (and thus cannot be scanned for vulnerabilities). These files don't have a password set on them but *do* typically have one of the following: a signature annotation added, limited permissions (blocking users from editing certain portions of the file), certified signatures ("Certified by Adobe Sign"), or files that have "Protected View" enabled.

I suspect that this is due to some funny business that Adobe is doing to the file in order to enable these special cases. I'd even bet that Adobe is *actually encrypting* portions of the file to enable these features.

Can someone explain/confirm that this is the case or explain why ClamAV would claim these files are encrypted?

Comment: Are you aware that PDF files can be encrypted using an empty password? For such PDFs Adobe Acrobat opens them without asking the user for a password. Files signed by Adobe Sign, for example, usually are encrypted with an empty user password.